# How to handle loading SQL queries into r that end with a semicolon

Tags: sql, r, readr

currently I'm loading a sql query that looks like this into R:

SELECT EMP_ID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_TBL WHERE EMP_ID = '0000';

I'm using the read_file function in R, however, this function doesn't work for SQL statements that end with a ";" semicolon. I'm thinking I should have some sort of condition that if the semicolon is in the second to last and last line, to skip the ;.

Any suggestions? I want the function to be able to handle files with a semicolon, so removing and saving again is no option.

Thanks!

Comment: no entirely sure what you mean. Do you want read_file to _not_ include the semicolon on the end?

Comment: You could use something like this if that's what you want: `gsub(';$', '', readr::read_file('test.txt'))`

Comment: I don't understand. If I have a file named `quux.sql` with `SELECT 1 as a;` as its sole contents, then `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, readLines("quux.sql"))` works just fine. It also works fine if I replace `readLines` with `brio::read_file` or `readr::read_file`. What are you seeing where you think that a trailling semicolon is breaking your flow? FYI, if you have multiple statements per file, that's a different problem, and not one that is supported by `DBI` (or `RODBC`, I suspect).

Answer (score 0):

The `read_sql()` and `prepare_sql()` functions in the [sqlhelper package](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper/) do a certain amount of sanitization, if you need to see the sql before it is executed. If you just want to execute it and get the result, it also provides `run_files()`.

(disclosure: I wrote sqlhelper)